# Just-in-time debugger and lucene

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, apache, lucene, wsgi

I am deploying a django web project into a real server. The code contains Lucene search engine. The whole system run well in my own computer. However, when I put it on real server, whenever I want to do indexing or retrieving (the rest of system is running well if I don't call indexing or retrieving), there is an error:

Visual Studio Just-In-Time debugger
"An unhandled win32 exception occurred in http.exe"
or
"An unhandled win32 exception occurred in python.exe"

After this debug dialog appears, the system will down totally and cannot be access anymore.

The real server currently has:
xampp 1.7.3 (bundle with Apache, phpMyadmin, mySQL)
python-mysql

### python-wsgi.

WinXP SP1
MSSQL 2005
visual studio 2010 SP1

I have tried the solution at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/24b356ad-59ef-446f-aa8b-df6b55fa78bb
But no result.

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On assumption that you are using mod_wsgi, make sure you are setting:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Note that you can only be running the one Python web application when doing this.

For why this may be necessary see:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

Comment: Yes, I used mod_wsgi. However, could you please give me how to set this one? Actually, my system can run when I type the IP from another computer. I think the mod_wsgi has done its job. The problem only occur when I want to index or retrieve search query of Lucene. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to remove mod_wsgi from httpd.conf and run system on localhost only, the same problem still occur!